# Unique HTML ID's that are not necessary

Tags: forms

I am new to Drupal and have encountered a weird issue. When using `drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_register_form'))`, it is using HTML ID's like `edit-name--6` and `edit-mail--2` for the username and email fields. The thing is there is no other `edit-mail` or `edit-name` in the page.

There is old code that was targeting `edit-name` and `edit-mail` with JavaScript. How can I get it back to outputting just `edit-...` without the dashes and numbers? Or how can I specify a custom HTML ID for those fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were to guess, these elements are form elements for fields that can potentially hold a several (or even an unlimited number of) values.  Or they've been built using Drupal's AJAX API, like this example...

`$form['input'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => 'A Textfield',
  '#description' => 'Enter a number to be validated via ajax.',
  '#size' => '60',
  '#maxlength' => '10',
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => 'Drupal\d8_module\Form\ExampleForm::sayHello',
    'event' => 'keyup',
    'wrapper' => 'edit-output',
    'progress' => [
      'type' => 'throbber',
      'message' => t('Verifying entry...'),
    ],
  ],
];`

When an element on a page has been built with Drupal's built-in AJAX handling, an ID to target (the 'wrapper' value) is specified.  This entire element gets swapped out with a new one but the id is modified by adding incrementing numbers to the end.

You can't really prevent this juggling; it's part of the Drupal AJAX implementation.  If you need to target those items with CSS or Javascript, the recommended approach would be to use (or add) other attributes that don't change.  Classes are an easy option, but you could also use any other consistent attribute.

Comment: You could form alter and add a "data" attribute that will never change.